# Ansible 2 conditionals using with_items in loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to run a few Ansible commands depending on the outcome of a conditional check in my tasks based on the presence of a boolean and am tying myself up in knots trying to get it to work.

The desired outcome is as follows, and **should be run for each item in the `hosts` array**:

- Check if the `lynchburg` variable is `true` or `false`
- If the `lynchburg` variable is `true`:

  - Setup the folder structure **if it doesn't already exist**
  - Create `gulpfile.js` from the included template file **if it doesn't already exist**
- If the `lynchburg` variable is `false`:

  - Don't setup the folder structure
  - Don't create `gulpfile.js`
- Regardless of whether the `lynchburg` is `true` or `false`, skip all tasks on subsequent reprovisions, as the folder structure and `gulpfile.js` will either be there or not (although this should be taken care of by the logic in the conditionals)

From the code included below, I'm seeing the following results:

- When `lynchburg` is `true`, the provision runs through as expected
  the first time around and any subsequent reprovisions also work as
  expected.
- When `lynchburg` is `false`, the `inc` folder structure **is** created, however `gulpfile.js` **isn't**.

The main loop the task should run through is the following:

```
vhosts:
  - site_name: sample
    lynchburg: true
```

and the tasks are as follows:

```
# Create variable to check whether Lynchburg has already been installed
- name: Check if Lynchburg assets folders have been previously created
  stat:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.site_name }}/inc
  with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
  when: item.lynchburg == true
  register: lynchburg_assets

- name: Check if Lynchburg gulpfile.js has been previously created
  stat:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.site_name }}/gulpfile.js
  with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
  when: item.lynchburg == true
  register: lynchburg_gulpfile

- name: Create inc folder
  with_items: "{{ lynchburg_assets.results }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.item.site_name }}/inc
    state: directory
  when: item.stat.isdir is undefined and item.item.lynchburg == true

- name: Create scss folder
  with_items: "{{ lynchburg_assets.results }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.item.site_name }}/inc/scss
    state: directory
  when: item.stat.isdir is undefined and item.item.lynchburg == true

- name: Create js folder
  with_items: "{{ lynchburg_assets.results }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.item.site_name }}/inc/js
    state: directory
  when: item.stat.isdir is undefined and item.item.lynchburg == true

- name: Create img folder
  with_items: "{{ lynchburg_assets.results }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.item.site_name }}/inc/img
    state: directory
  when: item.stat.isdir is undefined and item.item.lynchburg == true

- name: Create fonts folder
  with_items: "{{ lynchburg_assets.results }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.item.site_name }}/inc/fonts
    state: directory
  when: item.stat.isdir is undefined and item.item.lynchburg == true

- name: Create gulpfile.js
  with_items: "{{ lynchburg_gulpfile.results }}"
  template:
    src: gulpfile.js
    dest: /var/www/{{ item.item.site_name }}/gulpfile.js
  when: item.stat.exists is defined and item.stat.exists == false and item.item.lynchburg == true
```

**N.B.** If there's any other way to create the full folder structure easily without running five different tasks - one for each folder/subfolder - and someone could advise what that is, that'd also be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> When `lynchburg` is `false`, the `inc` folder structure **is** created, however `gulpfile.js` **isn't**.

I know how to solve it, I don't know (yet) how to explain it:

Change the order of expressions in the conditional:

```
when: item.item.lynchburg == true and item.stat.isdir is undefined
```

---

For some reason:

```
when: dummy.key is undefined and false
```

and

```
when: false and dummy.key is undefined
```

give different results.

It works as expected only when checking the top-level variable (`dummy is undefined`).

Comment: Thanks! I seem to have solved my original issue (see my comment), however I used your solution in another area of my Ansible setup which I was having trouble for exactly the same reasons with and it's worked perfectly.

Comment: This is because `defined/undefined` keyword is processed in a bit dirty way (see [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/ff20ab7d4439ad6e5ca099c428ac6d3f25a154e7/lib/ansible/playbook/conditional.py#L211)). So `dummy.key` breaks jinja2 expression if undefined, and second part of statement is not tested. You may actually write anything your want after defined/undefined, like: `when: dummy.key is undefined and anything and you and want`. To overcome this, use defined/undefined test as last one or replace it with `default` values.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed this in a moment of blind experimentation. I've removed the conditional check from the folder structure tasks, so it's just checking the raw `vhosts` loop, rather than looping through them first and then running the tasks on the results of the loop.

My tasks now look as follows, which seem to work exactly as I'd hope they would:

```
---
- name: Create inc folder
  with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.site_name }}/inc
    state: directory
  when: item.lynchburg == true

- name: Create scss folder
  with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.site_name }}/inc/scss
    state: directory
  when: item.lynchburg == true

- name: Create js folder
  with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.site_name }}/inc/js
    state: directory
  when: item.lynchburg == true

- name: Create img folder
  with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.site_name }}/inc/img
    state: directory
  when: item.lynchburg == true

- name: Create fonts folder
  with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
  file:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.site_name }}/inc/fonts
    state: directory
  when: item.lynchburg == true

- name: Check if Lynchburg gulpfile.js has been previously created
  stat:
    path: /var/www/{{ item.site_name }}/gulpfile.js
  with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
  when: item.lynchburg == true
  register: lynchburg_gulpfile

- name: Create gulpfile.js
  with_items: "{{ lynchburg_gulpfile.results }}"
  template:
    src: gulpfile.js
    dest: /var/www/{{ item.item.site_name }}/gulpfile.js
  when: item.stat.exists is defined and item.stat.exists == false and item.item.lynchburg == true
```

I'll leave it to the community to tell me if this is correct or not but, as I say, it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I'm missing something, but it *looks* to me like the `stat` tasks and the conditional checks that go with them are unnecessary:

- In the case of the folder structure, the first time the task runs, the directories will be created. But if it runs again on the same host, the tasks will be skipped, and you'll get output like this:

  ```
  localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
  ```
- In the case of the `template` task, you can set [its `force` option](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html#template-module) to `false` which means the task won't run if the file already exists.

Finally, your folder structure can be created fairly easily in one task by using [the `with_nested` style of loop (Ansible < 2.5)](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops), or [a lookup (Ansible ≥ 2.5)](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#complex-loops).

I'd recreate your playbook to look something like this (note that it will create the file structure in its own directory):

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    vhosts:
      - site_name: sample
        lynchburg: true
      - site_name: sample2
        lynchburg: false

  tasks:
    - name: Create required folder structure.
      file:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/var/www/{{ item.0.site_name }}/inc/{{ item.1 }}"
        state: directory
      with_nested:
        - "{{ vhosts }}"
        - ["scss", "img", "js", "fonts"]
      when: item.0.lynchburg

    - name: Template gulpfile into place.
      template:
        src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gulpfile.js.j2"
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/var/www/{{ item.site_name }}/gulpfile.js"
        force: false
      with_items: "{{ vhosts }}"
      when: item.lynchburg
```

Running this the *first* time creates the following result and folder structure. Note that:

- **Ansible reports two changed tasks**:

  ```
   ____________
  < PLAY RECAP >
   ------------
          \   ^__^
           \  (oo)\_______
              (__)\       )\/\
                  ||----w |
                  ||     ||

  localhost                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
  ```
- **only the `sample` host directory and files are created**.

  ```
  var
  └── www
      └── sample
          ├── gulpfile.js
          └── inc
              ├── fonts
              ├── img
              ├── js
              └── scss
  ```

If we run `ansible-playbook playbook.yml` *again*:

- the folder and file structure is un-altered, and
- **Ansible reports zero changes**:

  ```
   ____________
  < PLAY RECAP >
   ------------
          \   ^__^
           \  (oo)\_______
              (__)\       )\/\
                  ||----w |
                  ||     ||

  localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
  ```