# Ansible complex when statement - part of it is not evaluated

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I have got an issue with a "when" statement on an Ansible playbook.
Here is the task :

```
- name: Testing port 80 - 443 - 8443 on server_x
  wait_for: host=server_x port={{item}} timeout=1
  with_items:
    - 80
    - 443
    - 8443
  when: (sg_building == "TIGERY" and sg_marley_environment == "DEV" and sg_building is defined and sg_marley_environment is defined) or (specified_building == "TIGERY" and specified_environment == "DEV" and specified_building is defined and specified_environment is defined)
```

**sg_building** and **sg_marley_inventory** are defined on the dynamic inventory.

**specified_inventory** and **specified_environment** is defined with extra-vars (-e with the ansible-playbook command)

The first part of the when statement works fine (everything before the "**or**"), however the second part is just skipped (I've tried to switch place and it confirmed it)

Do you have any idea why the "**or**" is not working as expected ?

Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid `is defined` in complex expressions, because it is not actually a Jinja2 test, but a *catch* for undefined error.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608284/ansible-2-conditionals-using-with-items-in-loop/42608503#comment72351015_42608503) comment for details.

You may have more luck with:

```
when: (sg_building | default('') == "TIGERY" and sg_marley_environment | default('') == "DEV") or (specified_building | default('') == "TIGERY" and specified_environment | default('') == "DEV")
```

Comment: Actually I need `is defined` because I'm getting an error `variable is undefined` when variable is not in dynamic inventory or specified in extra_vars

Comment: oh I just saw the default('') : does is it set sg_building to an empty vars if not defined ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what `default` filter is used for.

Comment: Looks like it works as expected ! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

just tried it out:

```
- hosts: bidman
  remote_user: deploy
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="test"
      when: (sg_building == "TIGERY"
         and sg_marley_environment == "DEV"
         and sg_building is defined
         and sg_marley_environment is defined)
       or (specified_building == "TIGERY"
         and specified_environment == "DEV"
         and specified_building is defined
         and specified_environment is defined)
```

Command line

`ansible-playbook test.yml -i hosts/test  -e specified_building=TIGERY -e specified_environment=DEV`

The task is executed if the extra-vars are correctly set.

Which ansible version do you use?

**-- Added 2017/05/12**

Hi, please change the order of the statements like this:

```
- hosts: bidman
  remote_user: deploy
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="test"
      when: (sg_building is defined
         and sg_marley_environment is defined
         and sg_building == "TIGERY"
         and sg_marley_environment == "DEV")
       or (specified_building is defined
         and specified_environment is defined
         and specified_building == "TIGERY"
         and specified_environment == "DEV")
```

So that the `... if defined` is before the actual check of the varaible.
This will do the trick.

Comment: I'm using ansible 2.1.1.0

Comment: the difference I see is that i'm using the ansible playbook like this :  ` ansible-playbook --private-key /produits/inf-postinstall/cle/postinstall -i "server_x," -e "hosts_var=server_x specified_ak=AK_RHEL7_2_SEC_DEV specified_building=TIGERY specified_environment=DEV" install_hosts.yml -vv`. I'm gonna try to separate the -e arguments

Comment: Looks like that even by separating the extra vars the second part of the condition is still skipped

Answer (score 0):

On the meantime, I found another solution by setting an empty vars on the beginning of the playbook if the other variable is defined.
Then, I'm just doing my test without `is defined`

```
- name: Set empty SG building vars if specified_building is set
  set_fact: sg_building=""
  when: specified_building is defined

- name: Set empty SG env vars if specified_environment is set
  set_fact: sg_marley_environment""
  when: specified_environment is defined

- name: Set empty specified_building vars if sg_building is set
  set_fact: specified_building=""
  when: sg_building is defined

- name: Set empty specified_environment vars if sg_marley_environment is set
  set_fact: specified_environment=""
  when: sg_marley_environment is defined

- name: Testing port 80 - 443 - 8443 on server_x
  wait_for: host=server_x port={{item}} timeout=1
  with_items:
   - 80
   - 443
   - 8443
  when: (sg_building == "TIGERY" and sg_marley_environment == "DEV") or (specified_building == "TIGERY" and specified_environment == "DEV")
```

@Konstantin Suvorov : I'm gonna try your solution as it seems more elegant